# How to clear cells when using Excel Cascading Dropdowns

Tags: excel

I have a cascading dropdown which is populated using the excel Indirect function, this all works fine.

However when the value of the first dropdown is changed i want to clear the value of the second dropdown because this will now be invalid.

How do i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim oneCell As Range
    On Error GoTo ErrorOut
    For Each oneCell In ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
        If Not oneCell.Validation.Value Then oneCell.ClearContents
    Next oneCell
ErrorOut:
Application.EnableEvents = True
On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

For your reference > http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html

Comment: Is this possible without vba?

Comment: you should check http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html
I think they are explained without vb.

Comment: You don't actually set `Application.EnableEvents` to False in the code

Comment: `Application.EnableEvents` is `True` only when error triggered. some times, macro crashes while events are disabled.